# MySQL MATCH AGAINST doesn't return all fitting results

Tags: php, mysql, match-against

I have a table of, *to simplify*, **photo ids** and **tag ids**. And I noticed recently that when I use the MATCH AGAINST command it doesn't return all the suitable matches. Even though sometimes two rows contain the exact same text that's been tested against, but still one gets selected and the other doesn't.

Here's the table called **photos**

```
  id             | type | size    | tag                                                                  |
+----------------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IMG_1485197299 | jpg  | 1400000 | ImgTg_0000000000                                                     |
| IMG_1485429476 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195510 ImgTg_1485195592 ImgTg_1485195621 ImgTg_1486234725  |
| IMG_1485429627 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195510 ImgTg_1485195621 ImgTg_1485195592                   |
| IMG_1485429660 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195510 ImgTg_1485195621 ImgTg_1485195592                   |
| IMG_1485429669 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195510 ImgTg_1485195621 ImgTg_1485195592                   |
| IMG_1485429681 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195592                                                     |
| IMG_1485429687 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1486234725                                                     |
| IMG_1485429695 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195621 ImgTg_1485195510                                    |
| IMG_1485429704 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_0000000000 ImgTg_1486234725                                    |
| IMG_1485429710 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195510                                                     |
| IMG_1485429718 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195510                                                     |
| IMG_1485433986 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195510 ImgTg_1485195592                                    |
| IMG_1485433993 | jpg  |       0 | ImgTg_1485195510 ImgTg_1485195592                                    |
| IMG_1486234762 | png  |  143306 | ImgTg_1486234725                                                     |
```

This is the command I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE MATCH(tag) AGAINST('+ImgTg_1486234725 ' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

and its working fine with most of the table but for some reason it just doesn't work especially on the last row. Returning:

```
+----------------+------+------+-------------------+
| id             | type | size | tag               |
+----------------+------+------+-------------------+
| IMG_1485429687 | jpg  |    0 | ImgTg_1486234725  |
+----------------+------+------+-------------------+
```

**NOTE:** If I try and change the `tag` to a different `id` it works! But some `ids` just don't work

What should I do?

Comment: I should really consider having tags in their own table.

Comment: Perhaps the last row has some unprintable character as part of the tag name.  Does `tag = 'ImgTg_1486234725'` retrieve the last row?

Comment: Thank you Mr. @GordonLinoff .Yes it does but I just found the problem and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help
I've been trying to solve this riddle since yesterday, but I just found the mistake I made after I posted the question :D

I was using some kind of `latin`collation and I changed it to `utf8_bin` and now it works perfectly!